# React, Unterminated JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set up a basic example of react, this is my code to show the page

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App/>, Window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

and am getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unterminated JSX contents (22:13)

render(< App/>, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: {"Hello!"} should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use window

Simply write

```
 render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```